# IIS URL rewrite regular expression define required string block with list of options

Tags: regex, iis, url-rewriting

I'm trying to build a regular expression that matches the following:

This is the default English website URL: https://www.example.com/buy/apartment

This is the default German website URL: https://www.example.com/de/kauf/appartement

The expression I now have: `^([a-z]{0,2})\/(buy|kauf)\/([a-zA-Z0-9-+]+)$`

So, breakdown of what I tried:

- Have an optional block for the language: `([a-z]{0,2})` to be used a parameter value of `language`
- Escape the required forward slash `\/`
- Required block that can have only have either value "buy" OR "kauf": `(buy|kauf)`, no need to use this value as a parameter, so not sure if I even have to use parentheses
- Escape the required forward slash `\/`
- Required block to capture the home type: `([a-zA-Z0-9-+]+)` to be used a parameter value for `type`

My IIS rewrite rule:

```
<rule name="test rewrite">
  <match url="^([a-z]{0,2})\/(buy|kauf)\/([a-zA-Z0-9-+]+)$" />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="homes.aspx?type={R:3}&amp;language={R:1}" />
</rule>
```

I've been trying to test it here: https://regex101.com/
But I'm not getting a match on either these URL, where I would want them both to match: https://www.example.com/buy/apartment or https://www.example.com/de/kauf/appartement

URLs that should NOT match: https://www.example.com/en/all-objects or https://www.example.com/contact

**UPDATE 1**

I'm now down to this expression: `https:\/\/(.*)?\/([a-z]{0,2})\/?(buy|kauf)\/([a-zA-Z0-9-+]+)$`
See https://regex101.com/r/pieJWW/1

However, I seem to be unable to get the language parameter "de" in the 2nd URL as a group.

**UPDATE 2**
In IIS web.config I don't use the part `https://www.example.com/` to match on, but rather the part after that. So based on @Ryszard Czech's answer I now have this, but I can't grab the lang parameter, neither with `{R:1}` or `{R:2}`

```
    <rule name=""test rewrite">
      <match url="^(([a-z]{0,2})\/)?(buy|kauf)\/([^\/]+)$" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="homes.aspx?type={R:4}&amp;language={R:1}" />
    </rule>
```

Comment: Perhaps like this `\/(?:[a-z]{2}\/)?(?:buy|kauf)\/[a-zA-Z0-9-+]+$` https://regex101.com/r/DLp7by/1

Comment: please take a look at:  https://regex101.com/r/e5IsNa/2

Comment: @Flo You question is unclear. what type of site address you want the regex to be catered??

Comment: Thanks all. @ShekharKhairnar I used your expression as the basis for my test, but I'm running into a grouping issue...

Comment: You can try to write 2 regular expressions to match https://www.example.com/buy/apartment  and https://www.example.com/de/kauf/appartement respectively, and then add | in between two expression. such as: `^(buy)/([^/]+)$|^([^/]+)/(kauf)/([^/]+)$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```js
^https:\/\/([^\/]+)\/(?:([a-z]{1,2})\/)?(buy|kauf)\/([^\/]+)$
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/z5GI9b/1)

**Explanation**

```cs
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  https:                   'https:'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \/                       '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \/                       '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^\/]+                   any character except: '\/' (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \/                       '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [a-z]{1,2}               any character of: 'a' to 'z' (between
                               1 and 2 times (matching the most
                               amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of \2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \/                       '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \3:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    buy                      'buy'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    kauf                     'kauf'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \3
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \/                       '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \4:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^\/]+                   any character except: '\/' (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \4
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```

Comment: Thanks, this expression now correctly triggers my rewrite rule, however, the language parameter "de" in `https://www.example.com/de/kauf/appartement` is not passed as the `lang` parameter value. When I look at your sample on https://regex101.com/r/z5GI9b/1 I also see that the `de` value is not selected as a separate group, how can I do that?

Comment: @Flo The `lang` parameter value is in Group 2, I suppose it is `{R:2}`.

Comment: Thanks, I've added update 2 for some IIS specifics, could you have a look at that please?

Comment: @Flo But in `^(([a-z]{0,2})\/)?(buy|kauf)\/([^\/]+)$`, the `lang` parameter is in Group 2 (see https://regex101.com/r/z5GI9b/2). So, it must be `{R:2}`.